# how to plot sub df with values from whole dataset as x axis ticks in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a big data frame which contains thousands of data point and there is one column called period with the format 2011q1 stands for quarter 1 in 2011 from 2009q2 to 2015q2. After group by person, I got several sub-data frame and each of it only contains certain time interval instead of the whole time interval from 2009 to 2015. See image below of the period column of one sub df. Now I want to plot all of the sub df with the whole period interval from 2009q2 to 2015q2 as x axis ticks, and aggregate values from the Amount column as y values; the y value for a specific sub df should be 0 for any missing period, but what I could get now is a plot only with its own period column as x axis ticks if I used the code `person.groupby('Period').aggregate({'Amount':np.sum}).plot(rot='vertical')`

I am thinking about adding rows with missing time intervals to each sub df, but it seems a lot of work to do. Is there any way I can achieve it instead of adding rows manually?

[image]

Comment: Generate a list with all possible data and use this list as labels for axis x in matplotlib.

Comment: @StanleyR How to use the generated list as label in matplotlib? I am not familiar with the code.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html

Comment: @StanleyR Both of my x axis value and y value are something I got from the groupby and aggregate command, so how can I separate them for defining the x and y value in the plt.plot(x,y) function?

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly do it Stanley's way, and maybe use `full_df['Period'].unique()` to get your labels. But it sounds to me like what you actually want to do is go back to before doing the `groupby` and use a pivot table.

```
import pandas as pd


D=pd.DataFrame({'Period':['Q1','Q1','Q2','Q2','Q4',
                         'Q2','Q2','Q3','Q3','Q4'],
               'Name':['Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack',
                       'Jill','Jill','Jill','Jill','Jill'],
               'Amount':[50,20,60,100,200,
                        65,15,25,35,150]})
D
```

-

```
    Amount  Name    Period
0   50  Jack    Q1
1   20  Jack    Q1
2   60  Jack    Q2
3   100 Jack    Q2
4   200 Jack    Q4
5   65  Jill    Q2
6   15  Jill    Q2
7   25  Jill    Q3
8   35  Jill    Q3
9   150 Jill    Q4
```

Pivot the table, summing up the aggregated values, and call `fillna` to convert NaNs to zeros.

```
P=D.pivot_table('Amount','Period','Name',aggfunc=sum).fillna(0)
P
```

-

```
Name    Jack    Jill
Period      
Q1  70  0
Q2  160 80
Q3  0   60
Q4  200 150
```

And then use your usual tools to plot. E.g.

```
P.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

or

```
P['Jill'].plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]